# Appending Image in a dynamic table

Tags: javascript

so down here I created a dynamic table. In the cells of that table, I want to add 5 different images. 
It worked out when I appended each image individually to the cell but its not a solution because it will result in to many lines of code. 
This is why I defined a function where all those Images are in variables which I append in the Cell.

Then in the function for the dynamic table I call the appending function (c1.appending();)

so basicly its the same than before but its not working.....

```
function appending(){

var img1 = document.createElement("IMG");

    img1.setAttribute("src","stern.png");
    img1.setAttribute("width","25");
    img1.setAttribute("height","25");

this.appendChild(img1);

}

function tableAdd() {

   var table = document.getElementById("table");
    var row = table.insertRow(); 


    var c1 =row.insertCell(1);
    c1.appending();
}
```

Comment: You could just use the jQuery option `.append()`

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because c1 does not have any function named appending. Change your function's code with below code

```
 function appending(col) {
     var img1 = document.createElement("IMG");
     img1.setAttribute("src", "stern.png");
     img1.setAttribute("width", "25");
     img1.setAttribute("height", "25");
     col.appendChild(img1);
 }
 function tableAdd() {
     var table = document.getElementById("table");
     var row = table.insertRow();
     var c1 = row.insertCell(0);
     appending(c1);
 }
```

You need to call the appending function and pass c1 as a param to appending function and then append image into that param